# What is TILLING?

Tags: genetics, mutations, reverse-genetics

How does TILLING (Targeting Induced Local Lesions in Genomes) work? What is needed to perform a TILLING experiment, and what kind of information can we get out of it?

Comment: You can easily get the answer to this question in wikipedia article on TILLING